# one-dimensional Gelfand problem

Tags: calculus, analysis

For $t_0>0$, we define
$$I(t_{0})=\int_{0}^{t_{0}} \frac{dt}{\sqrt {e^{t_{0}}-e^t}},$$
how to proof that $I(\cdot)$ takes values in some bounded interval and achieves its maximum at
a unique point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $$F(t_0)=\int\limits_0^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{e^{t_0}-e^{t}}}=e^{-t_0/2}\int\limits_0^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}$$
The integral $A=\int\limits_0^1{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}$ is convergent as $1-e^{-t}\approx t$ for $t\to 0^+.$
For $0< t_0\le 1$ we have
$$F(t_0) \le Ae^{-t_0/2}\qquad (*)$$
For $t_0>1$ we obtain
$$
F(t_0) =Ae^{-t_0/2}+
e^{-t_0/2}\int\limits_1^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}$$
The condition $t\ge 1$ implies $1-e^{-t}\ge 1-e^{-1},$ hence
$$ \int\limits_1^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}\le {\sqrt{e}\over \sqrt{e-1}}(t_0-1)\le 2t_0$$
Summarizing
$$F(t_0)\le Ae^{-t_0/2}+2t_0e^{-t_0/2}\le A+4 \qquad (**)$$
Furthermore
$$ \displaylines{F'(t_0)=-{1\over 2}e^{-t_0/2}\int\limits_0^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}+e^{-t_0/2}{1\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t_0}}}\\ =e^{-t_0/2}\left [{1\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t_0}}}-{1\over 2}\int\limits_0^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}\right ]}$$
The function $t_0\longmapsto {1\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t_0}}}$ is decreasing, while the function $t_0\longmapsto {1\over 2}\int\limits_0^{t_0}{dt\over \sqrt{1-e^{-t}}}$ is increasing. Therefore $F'(t_0)$ is decreasing. Hence $F'$ may vanish at most once.
On the other hand by $(*)$ and $(**)$ we get $$\lim_{t_0\to 0^+}F(t_0)=0,\qquad \lim_{t_0\to \infty}F(t_0)=0$$
Thus the function $F(t_0)$ has a unique stationary point, where it attains the maximum value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea about how to calculus the derivative until seeing your answer.

Comment: You welcome. There is a general formula $${d\over dx}\int\limits_{x_0}^xf(x,y)\,dy=f(x,x)+\int\limits_{x_0}^x{\partial f\over \partial x}(x,y)\,dy$$ but cannot be applied as $f(x,x)$ is not well defined in your example.